# What tribe was Joshua from?

Tags: old-testament

I'm listening to a sermon about Aachen (from Joshua 7), when Joshua brings everybody in Israel before God, tribe by tribe, then clan by clan, then family by family.

As I'm listening, I am wondering how closely related to Aachen Joshua was. Presumably when he is doing this, there comes a place where Joshua is calling out his own. Who was that?

Comment: -1 for asking question on christianity.SE during the sermon :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the account of the spies entering Canaan, Joshua is identified as an Ephraimite (Tribe of Joseph, half-tribe of Ephraim):

> from the tribe of Ephraim, Hoshea the son of Nun;   [- Numbers 13:8  ESV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=num%2013:8&version=ESV)

and in case of any doubt that Hoshea son of Nun is one and the same as Joshua son of Nun:

> And Joshua the son of Nun and Caleb the son of Jephunneh, who were among those who had spied out the land, tore their clothes [- Numbers 14:6 ESV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=num%2014:6&version=ESV)

-- makes it clear that it's the same guy.